# 1 minute Delay in External Accessory framework showBluetoothAccessoryPicker

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, eaaccessory

I have to pair the classic Bluetooth device with my iOS application. For that, I have implemented showBluetoothAccessoryPicker with the External Accessory framework.

EAAccessoryManager.shared().showBluetoothAccessoryPicker(withNameFilter: nil)), this is the code I have used for that. Added "Supported external accessory protocols" in .plist and enabled Wireless Accessory Configuration from capabilities.

The actual issue is the picker displaying the device to pair with a 1-minute delay. What is the reason behind this reason and how can we resolve that?[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fJTj.png)

I could not find any solution for this issue. Thanks for your help